# submit checkbox value for the dynamic elements on html form

Tags: php, html

I have check box which will be dynamically added along with the textfields.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="namechkbox[]">
<input type="text" name="nametxt[]">
```

I will need to map the checkbox value with the text field. I found from other questions that after adding the hidden element over the input element checkbox.

```
<input type="hidden" name=namechkbox[]" value=0>
```

Since it's dynamic, it will add the index because of name[] in the name.

What is the way to handle checkbox with value submit for the dynamic elements?

Comment: Are you talking about retrieving the values of the check boxes?

Comment: Ya, while retrieving my value in php, I get the array with multiple indexes like when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: If you are dynamically generating these check boxes (if I'm understanding your question correctly), subtly change the index by a number (i.e., namechkbox1, namechkbox2) and then you won't have indexes that are the same. You can then run a loop in PHP to retrieve the values of the check boxes.

Comment: i donot want the checkbox name to have index number since i can have remove options to delete that checkbox and text field

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){ 
  $invite = $_POST;
  echo '<pre>'; 
  print_r($invite);  
} 


?>


<form method="post" action="">
 <?php  for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) 
   { 
   ?>          

    <input  value="chkbob1"  name="invite['id<?php echo $i;?>']" type="checkbox">
    <input  value=""  name="name['id<?php echo $i;?>']" type="text">  
<?php    
}

 ?>   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: My elements are dynamically generated so, every element will have same element like <input type="checkbox" name="namechkbox[]" value="letter" checked> and this will produce the mulitple index in the array.

Comment: ok...you want to get the values of each selected checkboxes from that array??????????can you paste here your array ?????

Comment: try this:  $namechkbox=$_POST['namechkbox'];
while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($namechkbox)) {
echo "$val,";
}

Comment: i have this block of two elements of checkbox and text and these can be dynamically added and remove in the page. So, i need to be able to identify these after submitting the form in php. I donot want index number like namechkbox[index_number]. So, is there way to identify these without adding index_number? That was my question.

Comment: you can use id1,id2 with loop ,do this with jquery or php   <input id="user1" value="user1"  name="invite['id<?php echo $i;?>']" type="checkbox"> with this,you can indentify ..which box is selected.

Comment: @ashish Try this coding:                                                          <?php
if(isset($_POST)){ 
  $invite = $_POST;
  echo '<pre>'; 
  print_r($invite);  
} 

 
?>


<form method="post" action="">
 <?php  for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) 
   { 
   ?>          
   
    <input  value="chkbob1"  name="invite['id<?php echo $i;?>']" type="checkbox">
 <input  value=""  name="name['id<?php echo $i;?>']" type="text">  
<?php  
}

 ?>   <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: Thanks. This is close to what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if user checks any checkbox change the values off to on and on to off viceversa.

for ex:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="namechkbox[0]" value="on" />
<input type="hidden" name="nametxt[0]" value="This my data string 1" />

<input type="checkbox" name="namechkbox[1]" value="off" />
<input type="hidden" name="nametxt[1]" value="This my data string 2" />

now you submits the from then check loop through array to check 
if namechkbox[0] value is on 
then take the value of nametxt[0]
```